# Where is file that saves Environment Variables?

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I am a developer and usually do stuff with the `PATH` variable. However, now there are too much path in it, and using a short textbox of Windows is a pain.

Before I happen to jump into a text file, that I think it is the file that saves Environment Variables, but now I can't remeber where it is, and Google gave me no possitive result too.

Can anyone tell me where that file is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Path` is just another environment variable, and is stored in the registry along with all other environment variables. [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/573818/1030702) identifies those registry keys.

The system environment variables are stored at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

The user environment variables are stored at:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
```

The system environment variables apply to every user on the machine. At runtime, the user path for the currently logged in user (you can find other users in `HKEY_USERS\`) is added to the end of the system variable (so, the final path is equal to "%SystemPath%;%UserPath%"). Unless you *specifically need* every user to have the same environment variables, it is *heavily* recommended that you only modify the user-specific ones.

As pointed out in the comments, the path variable is special in this regard. Other user variables will override the system one.

Comment: AFAIK, it is only `PATH` that gets the special "append" behavior – other environment variables override the system ones.

Comment: @grawity Hm. I forgot about that. Updated. Thanks.